# DSpace 6.2 Community List Modification

Tags: dspace

I've been trying to modify the appearance of the list of communities on the repository I'm working on. Essentially I want to remove the caption of the content description underneath the communities on the front page. I've attached image descriptions below.

I'm trying to get this
[image: Now]

To look like this
[image: What I'm Going For]

I can't seem to find the files responsible, I had initially attempted to modify the *_community-list.scss* and the *_community-view.scss* files in `[source]/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/`

But no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the following code to hide the display of that information. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/community-list.xsl#L66-L73

```
        <xsl:variable name="abstract" select="$data/dim:field[@element = 'description' and @qualifier='abstract']/node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="$abstract and string-length($abstract[1]) &gt; 0">
            <div class="artifact-info">
                <span class="short-description text-muted">
                    <xsl:value-of select="util:shortenString($abstract, 220, 10)"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi @terrywb I've tried this but there's still no change.

Comment: I believe that this page is cached by DSpace. You may need to clear the Cocoon cache.  Admin->Control Panel->Java.

Comment: Could it be possible to change it from the config file or admin settings?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. Caching was not the problem as it seems I also needed to modify */[source]/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/preprocess/communitylist.xsl*

Comment: Since the prior answer was incomplete, I suggest that you write a new answer that describes the code changes that need to be made to both artifactbrowser/community-list.xsl (from the prior answer) and to preprocess/communitylist.xsl.  Be sure to include code samples in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions above from @terrywb

> Comment out the following code to hide the display of that information. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/community-list.xsl#L66-L73

```
    <xsl:variable name="abstract" select="$data/dim:field[@element = 'description' and @qualifier='abstract']/node()"/>
    <xsl:if test="$abstract and string-length($abstract[1]) &gt; 0">
        <div class="artifact-info">
            <span class="short-description text-muted">
                <xsl:value-of select="util:shortenString($abstract, 220, 10)"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
```

Then in */[source]/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/preprocess/communitylist.xsl/* comment out line 138 to line 143 so that it looks like this.

```
  <!-- <xsl:variable name="description" select="$dim/dim:field[@element='description'][@qualifier='abstract']"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($description/text()) > 0">
            <p rend="hidden-xs">
                <xsl:value-of select="$description"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:if> -->
```

After building the descriptions below the communities should disappear.

---

I've also just discovered that this can also be disabled from the */home/dspace/config/dspace.cfg* file. Line 944 :

```
webui.strengths.show = true
```

Change this value to false so that it reads like so

```
webui.strengths.show = false
```